# Outputting all PHP errors to database not error_log

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, error-log

Is it possible to make all PHP errors be written to MySQL instead of to the standard error_log file. I guess this would be possible if i wrote my own error handler from scratch but i have a lot of legacy code in place and ideally i would just make 1 global change and that would be it. Can this be done?

Comment: I'm 99% positive  you can't just put something in PHP.ini and have it happen. That being said writing a custom error handler would take you about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think it can be done without building an own error handler, but technically, that is the one global change you're looking for.

Modified example from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
     // you'd have to import or set up the connection here 
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO error_log (number, string, file, line) ".
                 "VALUES .....");         

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
```

then

```
// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the php function `set_error_handler` might do what you're looking for. In the first example you can add some mysql inserts to write your errors to a database.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php