# PHP error_log errors to MySQL

Tags: error-handling, php

In a previous ticket i [asked about logging PHP errors in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911094/outputting-all-php-errors-to-database-not-error-log) which gives me:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
         // mysql connect etc here...
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `error_log` SET
            `number` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($errno).",
            `string` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($errstr).",
            `file` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($errfile).",
            `line` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($errline);
    mysql_query($sql);
    // Don't execute PHP internal error handler
    return true;
}

// set to the user defined error handler 
$new_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

I can make this work but only if it is triggerred like this:

```
trigger_error("message here");
```

However, I also want the error handler to be called for all errors such as syntax errors like:

```
echo "foo;
```

But these errors are just outputted to the screen, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to log such errors?

Comment: You can't handle non-catchable fatal errors with a php error handler (And a syntax error is a non-catchable fatal error).  It just can't be done.

Comment: I was wanting to capture any error within my system without needing to make any other changes. At the moment a syntax error would mean that nothing is reported at all currently

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - care to explain why its a "terrible way of error logging" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only handle runtime errors with a custom error handler. The `echo "foo` error in your example happens when *parsing* (i.e. reading in) the source. Since PHP can not fully parse the code, it can also not run your error handler on this error.

Answer (score 1):

If You're forced to test if syntax is correct, You can use php_check_syntax function, with filename parameter [PHP Manual php_check_syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php)

php_check_syntax also provides second parameter, witch when used will be populated by the error string, as far as i remember

Comment: I ofen use php_check_syntax in magic autoload function, when code is in development, it helps a lot in many problems, uncatchable in some circumstances (frameworks error handling is far from  good) :)

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed terrible way of error logging

1. You don't need not a single advantage of a database. Would you make a database lookup for the certain line number? Or order your results by file name?
2. database is a subject of many errors itself.
3. You've been told already that it's impossible to catch a parse error at the program logic level, because a syntactically wrong program will never run.

Let's take your code as an example. It will raise a MySQL error (because of poorly formed query) which you will never see. As well as any other errors occurred. That's what I am talking about.