# Distinguish new vs existing exceptions

Tags: php, database, web-applications, exception, error-handling

I am creating a PHP application and I want to display the number of times an error has occurred. The problem that I am trying to figure out is if an error has already been reported or if its new using the following values:

1. Message (ie: Attempted to divide by zero.)
2. Stack trace (ie: at componentNETapp.Form1.btnTrackExceptionsUn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) ...)
3. Source (ie: componentNETapp)
4. Target site (ie: Void btnTrackExceptionsUn_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs))

Thanks

Comment: Are you wondering which data to use? To me, I usually just group them by file & line, the rest is often data-dependent. As long as you are not putting to much statements in 1 line that works. Anything else (failed x times with this kind of input, y times with that kind of input) is probably overdoing it and a lot of work, and only of interest when actually working do solve it, in which case you don't want to see them grouped anyway.

Comment: So would the source variable work? Or would it change everytime an error is reported to the server?

Comment: Provide some example of code in here or at least what you have tried. I do not think somebody will write the whole code for you ...

Comment: So just to be clear again, I am not talking about exceptions from PHP. I am writing a application that is I guess what youd call "Runtime Intelligence" so whenever someone uses a software program it sends analytic data to my PHP application (such as feature usage, execution time, exceptions that occurred, etc). I want to know a good way to group the exceptions so I am able to see how many times each exception occurred and in what environment they are occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all Errors or Exceptions? PHP differs between errors and exceptions. Generally the [Error Handling and Logging<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) section of the manual might be of interest.

**For Errors:**

[`error_get_last`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/error_get_last) will return the last error with the following information: Type (integer), Message (string), File (string) and Line (integer). I would say this is self explanatory. You might also want to look into [`set_error_handler`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/set_error_handler) which will - next to these four bits of information - also offer you an *error context* you could make use of.

If you need more information about an error, there is also the backtrace in PHP [`debug_backtrace`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) which can add even more context.

**For Exceptions:**

Each [`Exception`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/exception) has similar members: Message (string), Code (integer), File (string) and Line (integer). It also has a Trace which contains more information and could be used as context. It's also possible to set a previous exception to nest exceptions. Like the the error handler, it's possible to use an exception handler as well: [`set_exception_handler`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/set_exception_handler).

---

With the information given, you should be able to handle and log all errors/exceptions in a manner that you can analyse them later on. Next to that it's also possible to make use of PHP error logging and to store those errors into a database. See [*Outputting all PHP errors to database not `error_log`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2911094/367456) for a simple example. I would say the key point is that you store the error information in a more or less normalized form, so that you can define criteria later on how to count/group them.

If you're looking for more infrastructure, take a look into the [apache logging services project](http://logging.apache.org/) that offers some tools (e.g. [a viewer](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)) and a PHP logger exists for it, too ([log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/index.html)).

But this is just exemplary, other tools exist as well, some of them are using a MySQL backend and you can not only track PHP but also other errors.

Comment: I am not talking about PHP errors/exceptions. I am talking about errors being reported from other languages (C++, C#, VB.NET, etc) and being able to group them together so I can see how many times the error is being reported and what type of environment (OS, CPU, RAM, etc) it is occurring in.

Comment: Then you need to normalize the logs, store them in a central location and use a tool to process these. Something comparable to apache logging or the log inside the IDE and such.