# PHP-FPM log errors in database

Tags: mysql, php

I'd like to log all errors encountered on the server to MySQL rather than error_log file. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911094/outputting-all-php-errors-to-database-not-error-log) already. However, the answer suggests to integrate a [custom error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

To be specific, I am looking for an option that could be integrated server wide (that doesn't mean prepending a file to every PHP file using php.ini settings), most likely C++ module.

- Are there any known option?
- Is it possible to create one?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Linux, here is a solution for you:

1. Make PHP write logs to syslog (`error_log = syslog` in php.ini)
2. Install `rsyslog` if not already installed (it's default on Debian I think, I don't know about the other distribs)
3. Configure `rsyslog` to write the logs to MySQL (see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_mysql.html)