# Hide error reporting and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

can server insert error reporting automaticly into database using php and mysql, if error_reporting = false and user not view the error in browser?i just need administrator get the error aotomaticly under user view.

and what script to get all error report?

Comment: Are you looking for a yes/no answer? If so answer is yes. Or is there something else? If there is, could you include in your question. Thanks

Comment: @Trevor i have update my question, with what code to get the all error report. maybe any example.

Comment: Error reports for php errors are logged automatically by the server in /var/log/error_log or similar (depending on OS). That is usually where administrator would look.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911094/outputting-all-php-errors-to-database-not-error-log for the log to db. Then look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini for how to turn off display of error messages.

Comment: @Trevor : thankyou very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hiding the error on the web browser** - from [Turn Off Display Error PHP.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini)
At top of php file add:

```
display_errors(false); 
log_errors(true);
```

**Logging to mysql** see the accepted answer at [Outputting all PHP errors to database not error_log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911094/outputting-all-php-errors-to-database-not-error-log)